# Jenkins - Continuation condition Status

Tags: jenkins

I have a Jenkins job structure which consists of a main job which is composed of many sub-jobs. These sub-jobs are grouped into different phases. At the end of every MultiJob Phase, I see an option called :

Continuation condition to next phase
when jobs' statuses are:

I interpreted it as follows: If one of the jobs within a particular MultiJob Phase fails, then Jenkins does not go ahead with the next phase. (if i set the condition as Successful).
But the help document in Jenkins page is sort of confusing me. It says the following:

> Define how to decide the status of the whole MultiJob Phase, based on
>   the statuses of phase's sub jobs. If the condition failed the build
>   will fail.

So, does it mean that this option only decides what the status of the MultiJob Phase is set as and does not determine whether Jenkins is supposed to execute the following Jobs or not? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

It means that depending on what you have chosen, if phase' statuses are not either:

- Always
- Successful
- Completed
- Stable or Unstable but not Failed
- Failed

MultiJob will not start running next phase and build will be halted.